# Is $\sin(p \pi/q)$ necessarily an algebraic number?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Here $p$ and $q$ are co-prime integers. Is it necessarily an algebraic number?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because it is a root of a [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials).

Answer (score 2):

For convenience, write $n=q/p$ and introduce the  extension  $K/\mathbf Q$ obtained by adding the primitive $n$-th root of unity $\exp(\frac {2i\pi}n)$ and a square root $i$ of $-1$. Since $(\exp(\frac {i\pi}n))^2 = \exp(\frac {2i\pi}n)$, the extension $L$ obtained by adding still $\exp(\frac {i\pi}n)$ is at most quadratic over $K$. In the end, $\sin(\frac {\pi}n)= \frac 1 {2i}(\exp(\frac {i\pi}n)-(\exp(\frac {i\pi}n)^{-1})$ belongs to the finite extension $L/\mathbf Q$ , hence is algebraic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

$$(\cos \frac{pπ}{q}+i \sin \frac{pπ}{q})^{2q}=\cos 2pπ+ i \sin 2pπ=1$$

Now expand L.H.S,  compare real and imaginary parts and put $\sin \frac{pπ}{q}= x$ you get the polynomial of which $sin \frac {pπ}{q}$ is is root

Comment: But don't the co-efficients of that polynomial involve $\cos( p \pi / q)$, which for all we know may be transcendental.

Comment: @user275313, you can use identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$ (edited).

Comment: Not to get rid of odd powers of $\cos$.

Comment: What powers of cosine come with sine. Off course odd, therefore  you  get $ \cos P(sin ,cos^2)=0$ $ (Im(1))$ . $\cos(pπ/q)=0 \Rightarrow pπ/q=2nπ \Rightarrow p/q=2n$ which is not possible because $p$ and $q$ have no common factors.